# How to avoid destructuring undefined values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

I get response `registryReportSettings` from server:

```
this.getRegistrySettings(registry.Id).subscribe((registryReportSettings: { extended: ReportPropertiesRequest }) => {
  const { objectProperties, reportProperties, textProperties } = registryReportSettings?.extended;
}
```

If it is `null` I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'objectProperties' of '(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
```

How to fix it using TS?

Comment: Start by properly declaring the type to match the values you're actually getting: `{ extended: ReportPropertiesRequest | null }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error means that you try to deconstruct a possible `undefined` (Because you use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining))

You can do

```js
const { objectProperties, reportProperties, textProperties } = registryReportSettings?.extended ?? {};
```

So you will always deconstruct an object

Comment: Consider using nullish coalescing operator `??` instead of `||`. In this context it wouldn't make that much of a difference but as soon as you are dealing with primitive  values, it will.

Comment: You right, I've updated my answer